# Maven: Build without the release:plugin and without a SNAPSHOT-version-number

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a multimodule-projekt that is currently on a SNAPSHOT-version. I want to change the version to a release-version, so a version number without the 'SNAPSHOT'-suffix. 
But I don't want to use the `release:prepare perform` process. I just want to change the versionnumber manually (`mvn version:set`).

When I try to build after I have changed the version, maven throws a "Unresolvable parent pom" and it seems that maven tries to find the artifacts with the new versionnumber in the remote repository. But since I didn't use the release plugin, it won't be able to find it there.

Is it generally not possible to use a non-SNAPSHOT-version-number without using the release-plugin?

Comment: Do you build the whole multimodule project? Which module fails? The master project or one of the modules? Show the coordinates of your modules, please.

Comment: Yes, the whole project. And it's the master-projekt (root-parent-pom) that cannot be resolved. When I try to build only a single submodule: some can be build - some not...

Comment: Coordinates: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT changed to 0.0.1 (by mvn versions:set)

Comment: Please show the coordinate parts of your POMs (before and after versions:set)

Comment: I use `mvn -N versions:update-child-modules` to align all child modules to use the correct parent. Will this help your case?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I had an error in one pom.. it really pointed to the wrong parent-pom. I wonder why it worked at all before I changed the version-number...

Answer (score 3):

If you run `mvn clean install` on the parent project locally, it will install the release version to your local repository.

Then running clean install on the child with that parent version should find the parent version in your local repository.